# Critical disorder strength for anderson model (for a discrete system)

Tags: anderson-localization

I have written the hopping matrix of a lattice in real space (in real space because i have disorder in the system and hence bloch theory is not valid). On-site disorder has been introduced through a box distribution function. I have followed exact diagonalization technique for studying the Anderson localization phenomenon. I have plotted eigenvalues vs DOS. In eigenvalues vs DOS plot as i am increasing values of W (disorder) the band is broadning. Further I have E vs IPR which is suggesting the transition from metallic to insulating state. I am not able to find, that exactly for which value of W (disorder) transition is occuring. In simple words I want to find the critical value of disorder strength. Can anybody help that how to proceed for that?

Comment: I think this question would be very useful also for others, if it had some more detail. Could you please write down the Hamiltonian, explain the notation, and maybe add a bit more on what you have done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The states which are most difficult to localise (i.e. they require the largest disorder strength to be localised) are those in the middle of the spectrum; also, the system becomes completely localised when all states in the system are localised. So if you want to proceed with exact diagonalisation (ED) and inverse participation ratios (IPRs), compute the IPRs of the states in the middle of the spectrum, average the IPRs over states and disorder, and do a finite-size scaling procedure.

In more detail, let us define the IPR in a $d$-dimensional cubic lattice with linear size $L$ for an eigenstate $| E \rangle$ with energy $E$ as [1] \begin{equation} \mathcal{P}_E = \sum_{j=1}^{L^d} \left|\left\langle j | E \right\rangle\right|^4;  \end{equation} the index $j$ runs over sites. For arbitrary disorder strength, it scales as \begin{equation} \mathcal{P}_E \sim L^{-D_2}, \end{equation} where $D_2=d$ in the metallic (fully delocalised) state and $D_2=0$ in the insulating (fully localised) state [2]. Now compute the average $\overline{\mathcal{P}_E}$ taken over states in the middle of the spectrum and disorder realisations: \begin{equation} \frac{\ln \overline{P_E} }{\ln L} \sim -D_2. \end{equation} If you plot it against disorder strength for several system sizes, you'll see it grow towards $d$ in the delocalised phase and decrease towards $0$ in the localised phase. The simplest estimate of the critical disorder strength is given by the intersection of the curves for different system sizes. A very similar analyis is carried out in [3]. A more accurate estimate can be obtained *via* a full-fledged finite-size scaling analysis (FSSA) [4].

As a closing remark, my personal opinion is the transfer matrix method (TMM) is worth looking into for estimating critical properties of Anderson transitions. Although it is likely unusal at first, it can reach much larger system sizes than ED (in reasonable time), and as such it allows for very accurate estimates of critical properties. I will not introduce the method here but refer to the online tutorial [5]. It is in fact a really good intro to investigating Anderson localisation both with ED and the TMM.

[1] See [Mirlin and Evers (2008)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0707.4378.pdf), Eqns (2.27)-(2.29)

[2] This you can derive yourself: in one dimension, in a disorder-free metal the wavefunctions are Bloch waves of the form $\langle j | E \rangle = \exp(-ik_Ej)/\sqrt{L}$, where $k_E$ is the wavenumber belonging to energy $E$; in contrast, fully localised wavefunctions are of the form $\langle j | E \rangle = \delta_{j,j_E}$, where $j_E$ is some localisation centre.

[3] I recommend [Pino, Tabanera and Serna (2019)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.02716), Eqns (2) and (3), and Figs 2 and 3. The paper discusses a model analogous to the models of Anderson localisation, with the addition that the transition to a fully localised phase is preceided by a transition to a "non-ergodic extended" phase; the latter has chracteristics of both delocalised and localised states. It also discusses a variety of quantities to probe localisation. See also [Mace, Alet and Laflorencie (2019)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.10283), Eq. (1) and Fig. 3. This paper is short and relatively easily readable, and discusses localisation in the presence of interactions (so-called many-body localisation).

[4] For a brief intro to FSSA and a python package see [Sorge (2015)](https://pyfssa.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fss-theory.html) (Last retrieved 14/12/2023.)

[5] [Delande (2014)](https://chaos.if.uj.edu.pl/%7Edelande/Lectures/?anderson-localization-in-dimension-2-and-dimension-3,48) (Last retrieved on 14/12/2023.) I highly encourage anyone familiarising themselves with Anderson localisation going through this tutorial. For high-quality estimates of critical properties of Anderson transitions with the TMM see e.g. [Slevin and Ohtsuki (1998)](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9812065).

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed information. I have another query: is it possible to keep the system size fixed and then find critical disorder strength using some other parameter say DOS?

Comment: I don't know how to use the DOS, or if it can be used at all, but with the IPR you can set a threshold slightly below one, and say if e.g. all states have an IPR above the threshold, your system is localised. Mathematically, set a small $\epsilon \geq 0$ and consider the system localised if $1-\epsilon \leq \mathcal{P}_E$ for all eigenstates $| E \rangle$. I don't really know a nicer solution, partly because localisation and the corresponding zero conductivity, the critical disorder strength, etc. are technically properties of a thermodynamically large system.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Actually I am dealing with a 2D system with 2048 sites. So if I consider different system sizes (the only possibility I have is 1632 and 512) say just 2. Is it possible to obtain critical exponents?

Comment: Ok, so depending on the symmetry class of your system, you may not even have a transition below 3D (which is to say you're localised for any non-zero disorder strength). If you want to obtain also the exponents, and not just the cirtical point, I suggest using transfer matrices. The method for the 3D model is described e.g. in Sec. 2.2 [here](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/16/1/015012/pdf). Alternatively, since you already know about IPRs, take a look at [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1107.5736.pdf) paper; it also has some nice visuals (Fig. 1), so worth checking anyway.

Comment: Indeed we see mobility edge in 3D case only in Euclidean space. But the case I am doing in 2D has curved space geometry and people have already shown the existence of mobility edge there. Further, IPR results I obtained also suggesting the existence of transition from metallic to insulating state. The problem I am facing is to find out the critical value by keeping the system size fixed. Considering different system sizes like L=30 28 26 24 .... like we do for 3D anderson model is quite easy. Changing just the value of L will give a different system sizes.

Comment: But the problem which I am doing now has a different scenario. For example as I mentioned, I am dealing with a system of 2048 sites, so for a different system size I can't have 2046 or 2044 sites. My system is very sensetive and I have to take care of certain things and thats why I want to keep system size fixed and get critical disorder with some other possible way.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. I have a couple of ideas, all of them have pros and cons. 1) Plot the IPR vs. E (energy eigenvalues) for several values of the disorder strength. You'll potentially see the band of localised states (having IPR close to one) overtaking the spectrum. 2) An extension of this idea is to produce basically the heat map part of Fig. 1 of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.0660.pdf) paper. What is shown there is something like the scaling coefficient $D_2$ for a fixed value of system size, giving you a phase diagram.

Comment: 3) Compute the IPR or its scaling coefficient averaged over both disorder and states for that part of the spectrum where the mobility edge disappears for the largest value of disorder strength. Then apply a threshold: if the IPR in that region exceeds that value, the model can be considered localised.

A request: as you seem to be a working on research, I understand you don't want to expose all the details, but still please do update your post with some example Hamiltonian, so that we can make this post useful for people trying to get into studying localisation.

Comment: Thank you so much for your ideas. I could produce a 3D view of eigenvalues (E) vs disorder (W) vs IPR and a bar plot for IPR.

Comment: Let me explain you the plot a bit more. X axis : E, Y axis: W, Z axis: IPR (colormap). at W=0 E spans as a disorder free case. for some finite value of W say 5 IPR starts showing up (which is expected to get the states in the band tails), even for further increase in disorder giving more states (IPR) and so on. at IPR=1 I am assuming the transition point for a particular value of W. I do not know upto what extent it is correct.

Comment: I need to give one more evidence for a critical disorder strength, where I am struggling now. Any other idea? I will frame the hamiltonian nicely and post it here for the assistence of others (but need some time).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150379/discussion-between-user3237992-and-zahid-malik).